# Why is the column reference ambiguous in INNER JOIN, but not in NATURAL JOIN?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I'm wondering why PostgreSQL produces an ambiguous reference error on this statement:

```
SELECT c from A JOIN B ON A.c = B.c; -- ERROR:  column reference is ambiguous
```

but not this:

```
SELECT c FROM A NATURAL JOIN B; -- OK
```

In both cases `A.c` must be identical to `B.c`.

Comment: JOIN returns both tables' C columns. Natural join returns one C column (same result), "table free".

Comment: @Patrick, well, I wrote a comment, not an answer... Anyway, the answer is there. The regular `JOIN ... ON` returns two columns C, (A.C and B.C), and you'll need to specify which one you want. A `NATURAL JOIN`, and also a `JOIN ... USING (C)`, returns just one column C. Then it can't be ambiguous!

Comment: So do you have your answer here?

Answer (score 2):

If you want an unambiguous column reference in an explicit join use [`using`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM):

```
select c 
from 
    a 
    inner join
    b using (c)
```

> A clause of the form USING ( a, b, ... ) is shorthand for ON left_table.a = right_table.a AND left_table.b = right_table.b .... Also, USING implies that only one of each pair of equivalent columns will be included in the join output, not both.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

In a `NATURAL JOIN` the fields are joined by name of the column, so if rows match then `A.c = B.c` by definition. The same is true when using the `USING` phrase: the match is made on the plain vanilla column names only. The difference between the two is that with the first option all matching column names are joined upon, while with the second option you must specify the like column names and you can thus be selective in which ones to include in the join.

In the case of joining with the `ON` phrase this equality of row values is not necessarily the case, even if the column names are the same. Consider this scenario:

```
SELECT c
FROM A
JOIN B ON A.c = 6 * B.c;
```

In other words, even if both relations have a same-named column, the values of those columns in rows from the two relations do not have to be the same to make a match because any kind of expression may be involved on the values of the either or both of the rows. Hence why you need to be explicit about which relation you want to select the row value from.

Comment: "the match is made on the plain vanilla column names only" - surely the types must also be the same (or 'compatible')?

Comment: "be explicit about which relation you want to select the row value from" - I don't think you mean 'relation'. I think this should rather be, "be explicit about which range variable (`A` or `B`) the attribute `c` relates to."

Answer (score 0):

There is ***one*** column named "c" in the result of the join in your second query.
There are ***two*** columns named "c" in the result of the join in your first query.

Hence, the column name "c" is ambiguous in your first example, but not in your second. The error message is clear. That's the extent of it. It's irrelevant whether the value of both columns named "c" might be identical or not. The reference is ambiguous, hence the error message.

SQL allows multiple columns to have the same name in a result set. But references must be unambiguous. A table-qualification would make it unambiguous:

```
SELECT a.c FROM a JOIN b ON a.c = b.c;
```

Or:

```
SELECT b.c FROM a JOIN b ON a.c = b.c;
```

***Why*** only one column named "c" in the second query? [Quoting the manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM)

> `NATURAL` is shorthand for a `USING` list that mentions all columns in the two tables that have the same names.

And:

> A clause of the form `USING ( a, b, ... )` is shorthand for `ON
>    left_table.a = right_table.a AND left_table.b = right_table.b ....`
>   Also, `USING` implies that **only one of each pair of equivalent columns
>   will be included in the join output**, not both.

Bold emphasis mine.